# FileSystemWatcher with ReadLines().Last() misses some new lines

Tags: c#

I have a FileSystemWatcher for file size changes to a chat log.

OnChanged() event I have File.ReadLines().Last() to get new lines, since that's all I want.

This is all working great except for the fact that it misses some of the new lines as they can come at the same time.

What should I do so this would track all the new lines?

```
private string _folderMyDocuments = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

    public void RunWatcher()
    {
        var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(_folderMyDocuments + @"\Entropia Universe\", "chat.log");
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Size;
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"^(?<Date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s(?<Time>\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})\s(?:\[(?:Team|Force)\]\s\[\]\s)(?<User>.+)(?:\sreceived\s)(?<Item>[^\(]+)(?:(?:\s\((?:(?<Amount>\d+|\w+)).+$)|\.$)$");
        var readLine = File.ReadLines(_folderMyDocuments + @"\Entropia Universe\chat.log").Last();
        var match = regex.Match(readLine);

        if(match.Success)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                RTB1.AppendText(
                    match.Groups["Date"] + " " +
                    match.Groups["Time"] + " " +
                    match.Groups["User"] + " " +
                    match.Groups["Item"] + " " +
                    match.Groups["Amount"] + 
                    "\r");
            });
        }
    }
```

**Sample log**

```
2013-12-21 16:26:13 [Force] [] XXX received a asd.
2014-12-23 14:53:27 [Team] [] xx received gfdg (5372).
2014-12-23 14:53:27 [Team] [] xx received jhgjh (9649).
2014-12-23 14:53:27 [Team] [] xx received dfgdfg (13)."
2014-12-23 14:53:27 [Team] [] xx received a sddd.
2014-12-23 14:53:27 [Team] [] xx received fdfd (71).
```

Comment: Remember how far along the file you have read.

Comment: When you get notified of a change start a brief timer (e.g. 300ms) and read the lines only after it expires (reset the timer if changes come in before it has expired). But you should also know: filesystem watcher is never 100% reliable, and the method you have chosen will kill your performance if the log grows too much.

Comment: track the number of lines the file had the last time and skip those (Skip(x))

Comment: Something very wrong with "to get new lines".  That code only returns the very last line, not the new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working.

I keep a record of number of lines (_lineCount) in the file and after OnChanged event happens, I read that many lines to go to the new lines and then do regex match on the new lines.

This is not efficient, but my file will always be rather small (max 10mb) so this shouldn't cause any problems.

```
readonly string _folderMyDocuments = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
private int _lineCount;

public void RunWatcher()
    {
        var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(_folderMyDocuments + @"\Entropia Universe\", "chat.log");
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Size;
        watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        var regex =
            new Regex(
                @"^(?<Date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s(?<Time>\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})\s(?:\[(?:Team|Force)\]\s\[\]\s)(?<User>.+)(?:\sreceived\s)(?<Item>[^\(]+)(?:(?:\s\((?:(?<Amount>\d+|\w+)).+$)|\.$)$",
                RegexOptions.Compiled);

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(_folderMyDocuments + @"\Entropia Universe\chat.log"))
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < _lineCount; i++)
            {
                sr.ReadLine();
            }

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                var newLines = sr.ReadLine();

                if (newLines != null)
                {
                    _lineCount++;
                    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(newLines))
                    {
                        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                            RTB1.AppendText(
                                match.Groups["Date"] + " " +
                                match.Groups["Time"] + " " +
                                match.Groups["User"] + " " +
                                match.Groups["Item"] + " " +
                                match.Groups["Amount"] + "\r"
                                );
                        });
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BTN_Start.IsEnabled = false;
        using (var r = new StreamReader(_folderMyDocuments + @"\Entropia Universe\chat.log"))
        {
            while ((r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                _lineCount++;
            }
        }
        RunWatcher();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Beyond skipping lines, your solution is also going to re-read the entire file every time OnChanged is triggered -- it'll be very inefficient.

What you need to do is keep track of the last known file size, and resume reading from that position. This will solve both of those problems.

Also note that `File.ReadLines` will lock the file for reading. This probably isn't what you want if you're monitoring a file another process is continually updating. When opening the file, be sure to give it full file sharing so there are no locks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried implementing your suggesting but couldn't figure out how. I also searched from the internet for several methods with no luck. Do you mind showing me how this is done? I'm sure it's pretty simple, yet still too complicated for my knowledge.

Comment: This is all actually a fairly complicated thing to do.